# "Кристаллы Сваровски": строчная или прописная?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Столкнулась в тексте с тем, что не знаю, как правильно написать "Сваровски" в названии кристаллов. С одной стороны, это фамилия основателя и разработчика этой бижутерии, а с другой, название уже давно стало нарицательным, как например, фамилия Строганова в названии блюда бефстроганов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В качестве нарицательного словари не фиксируют. Пишем с прописной.

Answer (score 3):

"Сваровски" - торговая марка, бренд по имени основателя, а бренды пишутся с прописной, как , например:"Популярная марка белорусского нижнего белья Милавица сегодня нашла своих поклонников не только в родной Белоруссии, но и в других странах мира". "Купальники «Милабель» - лучший выбор".

Comment: Но тут еще и в кавычках. Сваровски же в кавычки не берется.